# printing data member using class name

Tags: python, oop, constructor

```py
class Acc:
    id=121
    def _init_(self,id):
        self.id=id;
acc=Acc(111) 
print(Acc.id)
```

When I try to run this code , the code runs fine and gives 121 as output when I directly call the data member 'id' using class name Acc and remove the object creation line from the code but the code gives error "TypeError: Acc() takes no arguments" when I include the second last line i.e. the object creation line in my code.

Comment: you need to use two underscores, `__init__` instead of `_init_`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use double underscores when creating constructor method:

```
...
def __init__(self, id):
...
```

In your question code you just created a method `_init_`.